# Bitmap array resetting to Nothing after function (VB 2012)

Tags: vb.net, methods, multidimensional-array

Okay, basically, I'm assigning an array values inside a function of the class. But after the class executes, the array resets to nothing. Here's my code:

```
Public Class MoisacDialog
Public imgArray(,) As Bitmap

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCancel.Click
    DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdOK.Click
    Try
        Dim rows As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(txtRows.Text)
        Dim cols As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(txtCols.Text)
        If rows > 0 And cols > 0 Then
            ReDim imgArray(rows - 1, cols - 1)
            For i As Integer = 0 To cols - 1
                For j As Integer = 0 To rows - 1
                    Using fileImage As New OpenFileDialog
                        If fileImage.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                            imgArray(i, j) = CType(Bitmap.FromFile(fileImage.FileName), Bitmap)
                        End If
                    End Using
                Next
            Next
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Rows/columns entered are out of range.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End If
    Catch ex As FormatException
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid rows/columns entered.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

After `cmdOK_Click` executes, the whole array `imgArray` resets to nothing. If I use it like this in a calling form:

```
Using sizeDialog As New MoisacDialog
    If MoisacDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim ImageArray(,) As Bitmap = sizeDialog.imgArray
        _img = ImProc.PixelEffects.Moisac(ImageArray)
        picImage.Image = CType(_img, Image)
    End If
End Using
```

and use debugging view, `ImageArray` is set to `Nothing` after the third line, while it's still there by the end of `cmdOK_Click`.

UPDATE: I changed line 4 of my second snippet to `_img = ImageArray(0,0)`. The problem persists, a `NullReferenceException` is thrown and handled in the code enclosing my second snippet.

Comment: To confirm if it is something `PixelEffects.Moisac` is doing, temporarily change the line referring to it to `_img = ImageArray(0,0)` and confirm the first image is displayed and the ImageArray remains as you expect. My guess is `Moisac` is declared `ByRef` and it is setting `ImageArray` to `Nothing`.

Comment: I've already confirmed that. It's not `PixelEffects.Moisac`. In debugging mode, AFTER the execution of line 3 of my second code snippet but BEFORE line 4, the locals watch in Visual Studio shows that `ImageArray` is set to `Nothing` even after assignment.

Comment: @MarkHurd I updated my question with results from your suggestion regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not reset, it was never set in the first place.

```
Using sizeDialog As New MoisacDialog
    If MoisacDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim ImageArray(,) As Bitmap = sizeDialog.imgArray
```

Note that you’re using `sizeDialog` and `MoisacDialog` indiscriminately. `MoisacDialog`, when used as an object, is a default instance of the class of the same name. It’s unfortunate that VB allows this instead of catching the obvious error here at compile time.

To correct the error, simply use `sizeDialog.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: That fixed it! Stupid mistake on my part, I'm kind of used to strongly typed languages.

Comment: @Hameer Well VB *is* strongly typed. It’s just that for `Form` classes (and only for them) VB maintains a default instance collection at `My.Forms.…` which is automatically imported in the global namespace. That isn’t a flaw in the strong typing but rather in the namespace resolution.